# Ditado: Como digo em inglês "Deus ajuda quem cedo madruga"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução-inglês, tradução, ditados

Sei que ditado é algo a se investigar e que não é se traduz ao pé da letra pois há a questão de variação consoante a localidade. Gostaria de saber como esse ditado fica no Inglês.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE, Talles. Note que uma consulta ao Google por sua pergunta já conduz de imediato à resposta. Numa próxima vez, por favor lembre-se de que, via de regra, se espera que os usuários façam uma pesquisa prévia antes de postarem uma pergunta.

Answer (score 7):

O candidato mais óbvio, também sugerido, dentre muitos outros, pelo [dict.cc](https://browse.dict.cc/portuguese-english/Deus+ajuda+quem+cedo+madruga.html) e pelo [Google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=AzMoXaK8EsKtrgTw04yYBA&q=deus+ajuda+quem+cedo+madruga+em+ingl%C3%AAs&oq=deus+ajuda+quem+cedo+madruga+em+ingl%C3%AAs&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2549.7455..7673...0.0..0.144.1725.16j3......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0j0i67j0i10j0i203.iH86Hh8CUGk), é

> *The early bird catches the worm*.

[image]

Outra possibilidade [que se sugeriu](https://www.englishexperts.com.br/forum/como-dizer-deus-ajuda-quem-cedo-madruga-em-ingles-t864.html) é

> *Early to bed early to rise, makes a man healthy, wealthy and wise!*

assim como "God helps those who help themselves" - mas não considero este último um bom equivalente, pois nunca vi o provérbio ser usado num contexto em que "acordar cedo" não fosse parte do núcleo da mensagem.